# Swift: NSScrollView containing NSTextViews Doesn't Scroll Properly

Tags: swift, scroll, subclass, nsview, nsscrollview

I have an `NSScrollView` in which I wish to display several `NSTextViews` as shown below. (Much like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28856804/add-multiple-nstextview-objects-to-nsscrollview) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7435721/add-lots-of-views-to-nsscrollview)). I am adding all the different `NSTextViews` to an `NSView` using `addSubView()`, and then assigning the resulting view as the `NSScrollView`'s `documentView`. This is working just fine. However, the `NSScrollView` does not scroll properly. When I run the app, I can scroll up and the `NSScrollView` will push up and back according to its elasticity, but I cannot scroll down. Sometimes, however, and I'm not entirely sure under what circumstances, I **can** scroll down. I think it has to do with whether I have focused the `NSScrollView` or one of the various `NSTextViews`, but I'm not sure. And, to make matters worse, when I have managed to scroll down to the bottom, I start to have the opposite problem: I can push the `NSScrollView` down, but not up.

I think this issue has something to do with the fact that I have subclassed `NSScrollView`. When I built this same setup using an `NSScrollView` as provided by `IB`, everything is fine. However, when I subclass `NSScrollView` in order to make positioning the `NSTextViews` easier, the scrolling functionality becomes all whacky. Can anyone point out why subclassing `NSScrollView` makes this happen and what I can do about it?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that if I turned on the "Show Vertical Scroller" property of the `NSScrollView` via `IB` that the scrolling started working again. I have a feeling this is a glitch in `NSScrollView`, but I'm not sure.